# Extract given substring from a paragraph

Tags: java, substring

I want to perform the following functionality  :

From a given paragraph  extract the given String, like

```
String str= "Hello this is paragraph , Ali@yahoo.com . i am entering  random  email here as this one  AHmar@gmail.com " ;
```

What I have to do  is to parse the whole paragraph, read the  Email address, and print their server names  , i have tried it using `for`  loop with `substring`  method , did use  `indexOf` , but  might be  my logic is not that good to get it , can someone help me with it  please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Regular Expression for this case.

Try the below Regex: -

```
String str= "Hello this is paragraph , Ali@yahoo.com . i am " +
            "entering  random  email here as this one  AHmar@gmail.com " ;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@(\\S+)\\.\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
yahoo
gmail
```

**UPDATE**: -

Here's the code with `substring` and `indexOf`: -

```
   String str= "Hello this is paragraph , Ali@yahoo.com . i am " +
        "entering  random  email here as this one  AHmar@gmail.com " ;

   while (str.contains("@") && str.contains(".")) {

        int index1 = str.lastIndexOf("@");  // Get last index of `@`
        int index2 = str.indexOf(".", index1); // Get index of first `.` after @

        // Substring from index of @ to index of .      
        String serverName = str.substring(index1 + 1, index2);
        System.out.println(serverName);

        // Replace string by removing till the last @, 
        // so as not to consider it next time
        str = str.substring(0, index1);

    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: add a `\w` at the end to ensure the dot follows with the domain, in case OP later decides to drop the spaces after the emails

Comment: @AhmarAli. Is it a compulsion?

Comment: How about this? Pattern.compile("(?<=\\w+@)(?:\\w+\\.)+\\w+");

Comment: @AhmarAli. And you need to mark this answer as accepted, by clicking the arrow besides the answer.

Comment: @AhmarAli. Take the updated code rather. Replaced do-while with while.

Comment: @RohitJain  yes i have marked as accepted . did not know it , new to Stackoverflow . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a regular expression to extract the email. Start off with [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html) test harness code. Next, construct your regular expression and you should be able to extract the email address.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
  String e= "Hello this is paragraph , Ali@yahoo.com . i am entering random email here as this one AHmar@gmail.comm";
  e= e.trim();  
  String[] parts = e.split("\\s+");  
  for (String e: parts) 
  {
  if(e.indexOf('@') != -1)
  {
   String temp = e.substring(e.indexOf("@") + 1); 
  String serverName = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf(".")); 
  System.out.println(serverName);        }}
```

Comment: how can we split it by" , "  . it is a paragaraph .

Comment: extracts at most one email per comma. Split by something else, possibly by `@`

Comment: Now that you split by `@` you shouldn't look for it in the substring. It's no longer there ;-)

Comment: extracts at most one email per comma.

Comment: Extracts only `gmail` in `Hello, don't use example@gmail.com as I'm no longer using it. Use example@email.com .`. Should extract `email` as well.

Comment: Splitting by a character removes the character from the substrings.

Comment: Yeah. Splitting by whitespace seems good. You still need to add `if(e1.indexOf('@') != -1){...}`

Comment: ... and avoid the undefined variable. You declared the part `e` but use `e1` later in the code. Didn't notice at first, sorry.

Comment: Uh-oh. You've ended the 'if' too soon. It should encompass everything up until and including the `println`.

Comment: But I still admire the effort :-)